# DynamoDB: Appending an element to a list using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

This doesn't work. Is there another way to do this? `cord` is a list to which I want to add a map.

```
var params5 = {
  TableName: 'rides',
  Key: {
    'rid': data2.Items[0].rid
  },
  UpdateExpression: 'add cord :x',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':x': [{date: secondStartDate.toString(), latitude: xcorpassed, longitude: ycorpassed}]    
  },
  ReturnValues: 'UPDATED_NEW'
}
docClient.update(params5, function (err5, data5) { ... }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `ADD`, you could use `SET` with the `list_append` function (in general, AWS [recommends](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.ADD) using `SET` rather than `ADD`):

(**NOTE**: The `list_append` function name is case-sensitive)

```
var params = {
  TableName: "rides",
  Key: {
    "rid": data2.Items[0].rid
  },
  UpdateExpression: "SET #c = list_append(#c, :vals)",
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
     "#c": "cord"
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":vals": [{date: secondStartDate.toString(), latitude: xcorpassed, longitude: ycorpassed}]    
  },
  ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW"
}

docClient.update(params, function (err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err);
   else console.log(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the error code it throws it looks like you should change `add` to `set` and don't forget the `=` sign.

```
 var params5 = {
      TableName: 'rides',
      Key: {
        'rid': data2.Items[0].rid
      },
      UpdateExpression: 'set cord = :x',
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':x': [{date: secondStartDate.toString(), latitude: xcorpassed, longitude: ycorpassed}]    
      },
      ReturnValues: 'UPDATED_NEW'
    }
    docClient.update(params5, function (err5, data5) {
```